# Calculate percentage of progress between two dates in RoR View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker, progress-bar, date-range

I'm just trying to render a progress percentage to the view between two dates.

```html
<% start_time =  "2012-03-02 14:46:21" %>
<% today_date =  Time.now.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M;%S") %>
<% end_time   =  "2017-04-02 14:46:21" %>
<%= (today_date - start_time / end_time - start_time) *100 %>
```

**I keep getting the following error:**

> undefined method `/' for "2012-03-02 14:46:21":String

**My plan is to store that percentage into a bootstrap progress bar:**

```html
<div class="row daterangeBar">
 <div class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 700px;">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" style="<% ** progress percentage here ** %>">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: you can subtract or add only two date objects, first type cast these strings as dates.

Comment: How's yr percentage data supposed to look like?

Comment: while within the two dates render percentage progress - example 50% will be half way through the progress bar. Once it reaches the last day It will render 100% and the bar should turn green.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'time'

start_time =  Time.parse("2012-03-02 14:46:21")
end_time   =  Time.parse("2017-04-02 14:46:21")

((Time.now - start_time) / (end_time - start_time)) *100
```

Comment: require 'time'<% start_time =  Time.parse("2012-03-02 14:46:21") %>
<% end_time   =  Time.parse("2012-04-02 14:46:21") %>

<%= ((Time.now - start_time) / (end_time - start_time)) * 100 %> | this shows the following on the page: 6652.884938192538 not a percentage - did i do something wrong

Comment: @ManuelQuintanilla don’t do calculations in the view. Calculate the resulting value in a helper and use `@percentage` result variable in the view. `6652.88` you get is the percentage value, check your date ranges.